# Enclosure Memory Copies

Tags: javascript

```
function myClass()
{
  //lots and lots of vars and code here.

   this.bar = function()
   {
     //do something with the numerous enclosed myClass vars
   }

   this.foo = function()
   {
      alert('Hello'); //don't do anything with the enclosed variables.
   }
}
```

Each instance of myClass gets its own copy of bar and foo, which is why prototyped methods use less memory. However, I would like to know more about the memory use of inner methods.

It seems obvious to me that (1) below must be true. Do you agree?

1. Not only do distinct myClass instances have their own distinct copies of bar, but they also must have their own distinct copies of the myClass enclosure. (or else how does the bar method keep the myClass variables straight on a per instance basis?)

Now (2) is the question I'm really after.

1. Since the inner foo method doesn't use anything in the myClass enclosure a natural qustion is: Is javascript smart enough to not keep a myClass enclosure in memory for the use of foo?

Comment: The "Jibbering" JavaScript closure notes http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/ are a good read (and a lot less confusing then the spec!) I've wondered about #2 but it is an *implementation detail* and, if the specification is not violated from a semantic viewpoint (there are only limited ways to actually *access* an execution scope from code and excluding "eval" they are only via lexical closures), is entirely okay -- but I know not what optimizations different ECMAScript implementations perform.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably certain that any function has the a pointer to the entire state. It's irrelevant whether it references any variables it still has access to them.

Of course you do release that both bar & foo point to the same "entire state" of the object. So it doesn't take any more memory. I guess you have to allocate one more pointer internally so you can point to the "entire state" of the object but optimising for something like that is silly.

Whether it optimises it away is javascript engine specific. By all means read the chromium source and find out.

I'll see if I can dig some quotes out of the spec for you.

**Entering Function code from the spec:**

> 10.4.3 Entering Function Code  The following steps are performed when
>   control enters the execution context
>   for function code contained in 
>   function object F, a caller provided
>   thisArg, and a caller provided
>   argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the
>      global object.
> 3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to
>      ToObject(thisArg).
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 5. Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment 
>      passing the value of the [[Scope]]
>      internal  property of F as the
>      argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv.

That tracks your environment to NewDeclarativeEnvironment.

**NewDeclarativeEnvironment**

> 10.2.2.2 NewDeclarativeEnvironment (E)  When the abstract operation
>   NewDeclarativeEnvironment is called
>   with either a Lexical Environment or
>   null as argument E the following steps
>   are performed:
>
> 1. Let env be a new Lexical Environment.
> 2. Let envRec be a new declarative environment record containing no
>      bindings.
> 3. Set env’s environment record to be envRec.
> 4. Set the outer lexical environment reference of env to E.
> 5. Return env.

This tracks your environment to E which is the `[[Scope]]` of the function Object

> 13.2 Creating Function Objects  Given an optional parameter list specified
>   by FormalParameterList, a body
>   specified by FunctionBody, a Lexical 
>   Environment specified by Scope, and a
>   Boolean flag Strict, a Function object
>   is constructed as follows:
>
> 1. Create a new native ECMAScript object and let F be that object.
> 2. Set all the internal methods, except for [[Get]], of F as described
>      in 8.12.
> 3. Set the [[Class]] internal property of F to "Function".
> 4. Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of F to the standard built-in
>      Function prototype object as specified
>      in 15.3.3.1.
> 5. Set the [[Get]] internal property of F as described in 15.3.5.4.
> 6. Set the [[Call]] internal property of F as described in 13.2.1.
> 7. Set the [[Construct]] internal property of F as described in 13.2.2.
> 8. Set the [[HasInstance]] internal property of F as described in
>      15.3.5.3.
> 9. Set the [[Scope]] internal property of F to the value of Scope.
> 10. Let  names  be a List containing, in left to right textual or

Turn's out the spec is just telling you things you already know. Every functions contain the Scope. As the other poster mentioned it is upto individual implementation to "optimise" some of the scope away in terms of memory management.

If you ask me you really don't care about this unless you have >million instances of these objects.

The following block from the spec is more applicable:

> The outer environment reference is
>   used to model the  logical nesting of
>   Lexical Environment values. The  outer
>   reference of a (inner) Lexical
>   Environment is a  reference to the
>   Lexical Environment that logically 
>   surrounds the inner Lexical
>   Environment. An outer Lexical
>   Environment may, of course, have its
>   own outer  Lexical Environment.  A
>   Lexical Environment may serve as the
>   outer environment for multiple inner
>   Lexical  Environments. For example, if
>   a FunctionDeclaration contains two
>   nested FunctionDeclarations then the
>   Lexical  Environments of each of the
>   nested functions will  have as their
>   outer Lexical Environment the Lexical 
>   Environment of the current execution
>   of the surrounding function.

The two nested functions both have the same reference to the outer `Lexical Environment`

Comment: The definition of a closure is one that _has free variables_ thus if it does not access any variables it is not, according to the technical (theoretical) definition in fact a closure. If the JS implementation actually uses this definition or a looser one is implementation dependant

Comment: @tobyodavies Every function has the free variable `window` or is `window` not free?

Comment: `function(x){return x;}` doesn't reference `window`

Comment: @tobyodavies I have to remember what a free variable is again. Just because it exists in scope doesnt make it free.

Comment: @Reynos - a free variable must always be considered in the context of a code fragment - it is a variable that is used but not defined in the lexical scope of the code fragment - e.g. in `x=7`, `x` is a free variable, but in `var x; x=7` there are no free variables.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend entirely on the implementation not the language. Naive implementations will keep far more around than others. Any answer that is true for e.g. V8 (chrome's JS engine) may not be true for Spidermonkey (Firefox's) or JScript (IE) etc...

In my experience (this is definitely how GHC handles closures), the actual *code* of the functions (inner or outer) only exists once, but an "environment" mapping variables to values must be kept around for the closure (bar), so no, I wouldn't expect the JS implementation to keep around more than one copy of MyClass, but it will keep around a copy of its environment at least with `this.bar`, sensible implementations *might* realize that no environment is actually needed `foo` is not actually a closure, and thus does not need to keep a copy of the environment from the call to `MyClass` however do not rely on this behaviour.

Especially since the behavior of JS's `eval` function which evaluates a string in the same lexical environemnt as the `eval` call, it is quite likely that JS implementations *always* keep the lexical environment around.

Comment: @Tobyodavies is the copy of the environment the same for `foo` & `bar`. So if you need it one function it shouldn't matter that you have it in all functions? Do we only care about it if there is only one closure which doesn't use the environment at all?

Comment: The semantics of JS require that if you change a variable in `MyClass` from `bar` then access it in `foo` the updated version should be used (i.e. closures from the same environment must share the same environment) however it will still take a small amount extra memory potentially - an extra (possibly "smart") pointer for example

Comment: @tobyodavies the problem is also that optimising these things might violate the specification.

Comment: @Raynos Only if they can't proven to be valid/sound optimizations :-) ECMAScript only provides limited access to variables caught in bindings in code -- either as lexically defined or via "eval" (I am excluding "with" from consideration as that's a secondary issue). Since `var` is effectively an annotation (hoisted to the top of the function), the location of it's placement within a function scope is irrelevant to the optimizer and determining which execution scope a variable is bound in.

Comment: @tobyodavies But if the `eval` does not exist within the lexical context then it can be ignored as an "dynamic access-point" and we are back at "normal" lexical variable behavior.

Comment: @pst +1 & correct, I put it in there because this is how i'd implement this - lazily ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's ask some implementations what they do, shall we :-)

- [Spidermonkey: Internals-Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Internals/Functions) -- agrees with other answers. Talks about how closures can be classified.
- [V8: Are Closures Optimized](https://groups.google.com/group/v8-users/browse_thread/thread/3a4eeecb8569a251) -- very terse but does mention "static optimizations". Various articles on the web talk about "hidden classes" which, *I believe*, are how the V8 GC tries to optimize closures.
- Sadly those meager links are about all I can find. A direct analysis of the engine source-code is likely required to add more meaningful input.

So, yes, different engines *do* implement different optimization strategies when they can.